About Power Of Automation Desktop
I have 2 Datasets in the 1st Dataset i have Employee ID and in the 2nd Dataset i have available Employee ID's and their Username. I want to import single Employee ID's Dataset and then 2nd which is contains Employee ID's and Username. Following my questions:

I want to display Employee ID's and from 2nd dataset its username when Employee ID's match with each other.
When two dataset Employee ID's not match with each other then display 1st dataset employee id's when employee id's not available in the 2nd dataset and present in the 1st dataset

Please check this code i have available this code but no working properly:
Excel.LaunchExcel.LaunchAndOpenUnderExistingProcess Path: $'''C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\emp details.xlsx''' Visible: True ReadOnly: False Instance=> ExcelInstance1
Excel.LaunchExcel.LaunchAndOpenUnderExistingProcess Path: $'''C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\attuid data.xlsx''' Visible: True ReadOnly: False Instance=> ExcelInstance2
Excel.GetFirstFreeColumnRow Instance: ExcelInstance1 FirstFreeColumn=> FirstFreeColumn1 FirstFreeRow=> FirstFreeRow1
Excel.GetFirstFreeColumnRow Instance: ExcelInstance2 FirstFreeColumn=> FirstFreeColumn2 FirstFreeRow=> FirstFreeRow2
Excel.ReadFromExcel.ReadCells Instance: ExcelInstance1 StartColumn: 1 StartRow: 1 EndColumn: FirstFreeColumn1 - 1 EndRow: FirstFreeRow1 - 1 ReadAsText: False FirstLineIsHeader: True RangeValue=> Dataset1Data
Excel.ReadFromExcel.ReadCells Instance: ExcelInstance2 StartColumn: 1 StartRow: 1 EndColumn: FirstFreeColumn2 - 1 EndRow: FirstFreeRow2 - 1 ReadAsText: False FirstLineIsHeader: True RangeValue=> Dataset2Data
Excel.CloseExcel.Close Instance: ExcelInstance1
Excel.CloseExcel.Close Instance: ExcelInstance2
Excel.LaunchExcel.LaunchUnderExistingProcess Visible: True Instance=> ExcelInstance3

SET NewVar TO 2
SET FoundMatch1 TO False
LOOP FOREACH CurrentItem IN Dataset1Data
    SET FoundMatch2 TO False
    LOOP FOREACH CurrentItem2 IN Dataset2Data
        IF CurrentItem['Paycom ID'] = CurrentItem2['Employee ID'] THEN
            Excel.WriteToExcel.WriteCell Instance: ExcelInstance3 Value: CurrentItem['Paycom ID'] Column: $'''A''' Row: NewVar
            Excel.WriteToExcel.WriteCell Instance: ExcelInstance3 Value: CurrentItem2['USERNAME'] Column: $'''B''' Row: NewVar
            SET FoundMatch1 TO True
            SET FoundMatch2 TO True
            BREAK LOOP
        END
    END

    IF NOT FoundMatch2 THEN
        Excel.WriteToExcel.WriteCell Instance: ExcelInstance3 Value: CurrentItem['Paycom ID'] Column: $'''C''' Row: NewVar
        Excel.WriteToExcel.WriteCell Instance: ExcelInstance3 Value: 'Not Found' Column: $'''B''' Row: NewVar
    END

    Variables.IncreaseVariable Value: NewVar IncrementValue: 1
END

LOOP FOREACH CurrentItem IN Dataset2Data
    IF NOT FoundMatch1 THEN
        Excel.WriteToExcel.WriteCell Instance: ExcelInstance3 Value: CurrentItem['Employee ID'] Column: $'''A''' Row: NewVar
        Excel.WriteToExcel.WriteCell Instance: ExcelInstance3 Value: 'Not Found' Column: $'''B''' Row: NewVar
        Variables.IncreaseVariable Value: NewVar IncrementValue: 1
    END
END

Excel.CloseExcel.CloseAndSaveAs Instance: ExcelInstance3 DocumentFormat: Excel.ExcelFormat.OpenXmlWorkbook DocumentPath: $'''C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Result.xlsx'''

